# Adding jitter on large data set - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, jitter, large-data

I am trying to apply jitter while plotting with ggplot2 as follows:

`timeClusterPlot <-ggplot(timeClusterDf, aes(Location,time)) + labs(x='Location', y='Time')`
`timeClusterPlot <- timeClusterPlot + 
geom_point(aes(colour=cluster),position=position_jitter(w=0.01,h=0.01))`

Here is the result: 
[image: Result]

Due to the size of my data set, the density of points are so high that I think when applying jitter, there isn't enough sparsity to get the result I am looking for unless I severely increase the **height** and the **width** parameters. Any suggestions?

Comment: Add transparency (set, for example, `alpha=0.2` in `geom_point`). You could also plot a random sample of points rather than all of them.

Comment: Yep, transparency, and maybe make the points smaller so there's less overlap.

Comment: Yes randomly sampling and adjusting transparency should help! Thanks you :)